# Define a React component's drawing code in terms of its parent

Tags: reactjs, svg

Lets say I want to draw a SVG line path that scales dynamically to the context it is in.  The line goes from the top left of its container to the bottom right.  So if the dimension of the container is 100x100 the line path (d attribute) is `"M0,0 L100,100"` or for 50x150 its `"M0,0 L50,150"`.

So e.g.

```
class Line extends Component {
    render() {
       const { x1, x2, y1, y2 } = ???
       return <svg><line d={`L${x1},${y1} M${x2}${y2}`} /></svg>
    }
}
```

I have the same problem with canvas, svg and any drawing code I do.  When I look at tutorials I always see hard coded values.  But what if I want my code to be dynamic as above so that with the following:

```
<div className="col1"><Line /></div>
<div className="col2"><Line /></div>
<div className="col3"><Line /></div>
```

the lines would extend from the top-left to the bottom-right no matter how big these divs become, the drawing code always draws from top-left to bottom-right.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without JS. Here's one way to do it. The SVG line will follow the boundary of the `div` element.

html

```
<div class="col">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" d="M0 0 100 100" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

css

```
.col {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.col svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

If you really want to provide dynamically values, then you need to create a React component for the div. On `componentDidMount` you calculate the boundary of the element.

E.g. the Div component

```
componentDidMount(){
  const domRect = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getBoundingClientRect();
  this.setState({
    width: domRect.width,
    height: domRect.height
  })
}
```

Then you have the width and height values which you can provide to the Line component using props.